# Starting and monitoring processes on a node.js web-application

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

I'm currently developing a web application that can start a sort of build process using a command line tool on the server related to a persited model in my application. I'm using `child_process.spawn` to spawn a process and monitor the output of the build tool.

```
var command = spawn('command', args, {cwd: '/tmp'});
command("data", function(chunk) {
    debug('received chunk ',chunk);
});
```

Starting the process when a request comes in and waiting until it finishes to send a response including the cli output (about 300~500 lines) to the client just takes too long.

The best way would be to take the request, spawn a process, save a link to the process in the database and return a response that the process started.

Another request could then ask for the state of the process, the output of the cli so far and stream the newly created output to the client. Kind of like jenkins does handle builds.

My Question now is how to store a link to my spawnd `command` variable that runs the process and how to catch up on that process when another request from the client comes in to serve him the chunks through streaming fe?

I'm using loopback for the node.js backend and angular on the frontend.
I know this could sound a bit confusing so please feel free to ask any Question.

Comment: i ended up holding the spawned processes in memory and linking them to my database by the process id. if my node server crashes the variables hold in memory are gone but thats ok since all child_processes get also killed. if anyone finds a soltion, go for it!